# Is it possible to create a docker swarm cluster using nodes on different cloud providers?

Tags: docker, devops, swarm

Is it possible to create a docker swarm cluster using nodes on different cloud providers?

Let's say some of them on AWS, some on GCE and some on Azure?

Comment: Why don't you try first before asking?

Comment: sadly @JulienBernu i leave on a country where i do not have enough money to pay for all those clouds not even one to test it. I would really do that if y can, but since i cant i thought reaching the community. I never expect people to angry to throw blames before help. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding, as long as your nodes could access each other, then you will be able to create a swarm cluster. It doesn't matter who are your cloud providers or where your node located.

If you read the [swarm deployment document](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-manual/#/step-5-create-swarm-cluster) carefully, you will find the critical thing of deploying a cluster is "let the compute nodes to communicate with controller node". Assume you already have a controller node with swarm and a discovery service (such as consul or etcd) both installed, the you can add a compute node like this:

```
$ docker run -d swarm join --advertise=<node_ip>:2375 consul://<consul_ip>:8500
```

Where `node_ip` and `consul_ip` should be your controller node's IP.

So the tricky part is, can you make your nodes communicate to each other? Actually this question is not easy to answer. You need to care about IP allocation, network design, routers etc.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Look at Docker Machine for a quick way of setting up the basic infrastructure.

[Docker Machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/)